# Why is the IsGrounded function True when I press space, and not when im on the ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm new to Unity and I'm trying to make it so the player can't jump while they're already jumping using **IsGrounded** which should check if they're on the ground, but instead if press space then **IsGrounded** true. It might be an issue within Unity itself but im not sure. Thanks!
The code:

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;

    float xInput, yInput;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask lm;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private BoxCollider2D bc;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }
    private void Awake()
     {
      rb = transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
      bc = transform.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();

    }



    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (IsGrounded() && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            float jumpVelocity = 25f;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpVelocity;
            Debug.Log("IsGrounded");
        } 
        xInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        transform.Translate(xInput * moveSpeed, 0, 0);
        PlatformerMove();
        
    }

    void PlatformerMove()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed * xInput, rb.velocity.y);

    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        RaycastHit2D rc = Physics2D.BoxCast(bc.bounds.center, bc.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down * .1f, lm);
        return rc.collider != null;

    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a

```
Physics2D.BoxCast(bc.bounds.center, bc.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down * .1f, lm);
```

Now if you look at the parameters of [`Physics2D.BoxCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.BoxCast.html)

> ```
> public static RaycastHit2D BoxCast(
>     Vector2 origin, Vector2 size, 
>     float angle, Vector2 direction, 
>     float distance = Mathf.Infinity, 
>     int layerMask = Physics2D.AllLayers, 
>     float minDepth = -Mathf.Infinity, 
>     float maxDepth = Mathf.Infinity
> );
> ```

You are passing in

- **`origin`** = `bc.bounds.center`
- **`size`** = `bc.bounds.size`
- **`direction`** = `Vector2.down` (the magnitude doesn't matter for a distance!)
- **`distance`** = `lm` (I think you note the issue now) => I suppose this is a layermask -> some rather big integer -> you shoot very far -> probably **always** hit the something
- **`layerMask`** = `Physics2D.AllLayers`

In general, since it is a Box**cast** this means you are shooting a box into space and check if on its way it is hitting something.

If that's intended you would rather pass in

```
RaycastHit2D rc = Physics2D.BoxCast(bc.bounds.center, bc.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, 0.1f, lm);
```

---

Otherwise I suppose you rather would want to use [`Physics2D.OverlapBox`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapBox.html) instead which rather checks for an overlap in a fixed position/area without shooting it anywhere

```
RaycastHit2D rc = Physics2D.OverlapBox(bc.bounds.center, bc.bounds.size, 0f, lm);
```